# Включение состояния checked radio кнопки в зависимости от полученной внешней переменной

Tags: javascript, html, radio

Есть две радиокнопки. Выполнены в виде переключателя. При нажатии отправляют переменную на сервер и должны изменять свой цвет. Сервер отправляет значение в переменную: %STATE%. Это значение - "включены" или "выключены". Сервер может отправить только одно значение за 1 запрос. При этом это значение на сервере сохраняется, пока сервером не будет получена другая переменная. При отправке переменной на сервер, страница перезагружается. Как сделать выбор (checked) состояния радиокнопок в зависимости от полученной переменной %STATE% с помощью jS? Весь код работает, просто кнопки не меняют цвет. Использую JS скрипт, но в части if - else скрипт не работает. Получаю в консоли только значение "нет", независимо от того какую кнопку нажимаю.
Варианты ответа в консоли браузера:
выключены
нет,
включены
нет.

```js
function init() {
  var par = document.getElementById("nl");
  console.log(par.innerHTML);
  if (par.innerHTML == "выключены") {
    // var scoop = document.getElementById("fid-1");
    // scoop.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
    // scoop.checked = true;
    console.log("Да");
  } else {
    // var scoop = document.getElementById("fid-2");
    //  scoop.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
    //  scoop.checked = true;
    console.log("Нет");
  }
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<p>Ближние светильники <strong id="nl"> %STATE%</strong></p>
<div class="form_toggle">
  <div class="form_toggle-item item-1">
    <input id="fid-1" type="radio" name="radio1" onclick='location.href="off"' value="off" />
    <label for="fid-1">Выкл</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_toggle-item item-2">
    <input id="fid-2" type="radio" name="radio1" onclick='location.href="on"' value="on" />
    <label for="fid-2">ВКЛ</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ну допустим вы получаете `Boolean`, то есть `state` либо `true` либо `false`.  Тогда будет `(state ? inputFid1 : inputFid2).checked = true;`  где `inputFid1` и `inputFid2` ваши radio переключатели соответственно.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но к сожалению не смог воспользоваться Вашим вариантом. Как я понимаю ошибка в скрипте в строке начинающейся с "if". Если я применяю == как в данном примере, то независимо от того, какой переключатель я нажимаю, выполняется только часть кода начинающегося со строки "else". А если вместо == я применяю !=, то выполняется часть кода между "if" и "else". И подсвечивается одна радиокнопка.

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось просто: innerHTML меняем на innerText.